# Where is the app.config installed for a SharpShell assembly?

Tags: c#, contextmenu, windows-shell, sharpshell

I created a shell context extension using the `SharpShell` nuget package. I then used the `ServerManager` executable to help install/register my assembly, and it works.

The problem I am running into is that I have no idea where the app.config is installed. I have a user setting that I want to adjust, but I can't find the proper app.config file. Where exactly does the app.config get stored for shell extension assemblies?

Answer (score 2):

Using the normal configuration manager, the `xxx.exe.config` file will be read in the directory where the main (EXE) assembly is, not the DLL.

This makes it difficult if someone wants a config for a DLL. I stumbled about this some time ago, where I had an application based on MS Access with many additional libraries. One of them needed a config file. We had to install a msaccess.exe.config in the MS access application directory. Not very elegant.

So, in your case it probably will be `C:\Windows\explorer.exe.config`

See also
[inherit the proper app.config in a program started from context menu by SharpShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905700/inherit-the-proper-app-config-in-a-program-started-from-context-menu-by-sharpshe)